# WPF background is renderin wrong

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to put button on chrome and i found this solution  [Solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968743/how-to-draw-content-in-non-client-area-properly-with-regular-caption-buttons)

But it is rendering backgrond as black. I have not set it black anywhere, how does it is black ?

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0.5,28,0,0.5" NonClientFrameEdges="Right"/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
<Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=Content}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Template>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

        <Button Content="Help" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Height="28" Margin="0,0,120,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

[image: WPF window]

Comment: Does your window have a content?

Comment: edited question

Comment: Try two quick things. First set your StackPanel's alignments to `Stretch`. Second, play with `GlassFrameThickness` to see if that has any effect.

Comment: no diff only chrome lenght reduced, whee is <ContentPresenter content binding to , may be i can change template there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to paint the background yourself. Put the `Button` in the `ControlTemplate` and move the `ContentPresenter` to another row where you specify a background:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindoq"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0.5,28,0,0.5" NonClientFrameEdges="Right"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Window.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button Content="Help" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Height="28" Margin="0,0,120,0"
                            Click="Button_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Border Background="White"  Grid.Row="1">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=Content}" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The black part you see is an unpainted area. This is black by default and not white.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's with your control template please try changing the control template

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}" >
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                       Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"></Rectangle>
                <!-- This is the ContentPresenter that displays the window content. -->
                <Border Margin="0,40,0,5" >
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
                <!--This is the transparent white rectangle that goes behind the window content.-->
                <Border Margin="1,40,1,5" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" 
                             Grid.ZIndex="-1">
                    <Rectangle Fill="White" Opacity="0.5" />
                </Border>

                <!-- Window Title -->
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Left" 
                       Text="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                     {RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: it will cover entire window , even close button

Answer (score 0):

1 in "....",you set "ControlTemplate" to show content only
2 then in content，Grid is without any style(may be background is null)

do some test
add a click handler of button

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
   var color = Grid.Background;//is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you can achieve the effect you're after without using any 3rd-party solutions. Simply set your Button's `VerticalAlignment` to `Top` and then use negative top `Margin` to move it onto the Title Bar. I have used that technique in the past to create windows like this:

[image]

Remember however that in this case you'll need to set your `WindowStyle` to `None` and `AllowsTransparency` to `True`. You'll need to draw the system buttons yourself if your application needs them.